# least absolute deviation version of deming

Tags: r, regression, total-least-squares, least-absolute-deviations

Based on what I know, deming minimizes the sum of square of perpendicular distance to the regression line. Is there a package in R that can run regression that minimize the sum of absolute value of perpendicular distance (Some what like a least absolute deviation version of deming)? Thanks a lot!